# Log file size in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems

If simply movies, tv shows, etc... from a shared folder in windows into a folder in Ubuntu 16 for use with plex and then importing the shows into plex, does this make the usr>log file large and if so, why? How can I safely and correctly reduce the log file size as shown by using Baobab from the 88gb it shows now for log?

Thanks much.

Comment: Log is really in `/usr/log` and not in `/var/log`? What are typicaly contents of the log?

Comment: Which file specifically is so big? Like @xenoid says, find out why the logs are so big and stop whatever keeps adding to them. (And you mean the logs are in /var/log, and not /usr/log?)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a logrotate file to /etc/logrotate.d/
Such as:

```
/path/to/logfile{
copytruncate
rotate 9
size 5M
compress
missingok
}
```

Important is the `size 5M` part (define the size you want) and you have to specify the `/path/to/logfile`

According to https://serverfault.com/q/147476/391060, logrotate is running daily. You could move `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` to `/etc/cron.hourly/` so the logs are checked hourly, if the size limit is reached and compress the old log.

Comment: or anyone - so then the log would have gotten large from logging the 2tb of movies from a windows machine over to a share on my Ubuntu machine?